# Github actions: Schedule an automatic pull request with all wildcard branches

Tags: github-actions, branch, wildcard, pull-request, schedule

I am using Github Actions and I am trying to schedule a pull-request to all wildcard branches. Is there a way to do this? Currently I am using peter-evans/create-pull-request@v5 but it does not accept wildcard branches.

```yaml
name: Test-Schedule

on:
  schedule:
    - cron: '*/10 * * * *'

jobs:
  Automate-Pull-Requests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Automate Pull Requests

    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Sample Pull Request
        uses: peter-evans/create-pull-request@v5
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.TEST }}
          commit-message: "test-schedule"
          title: test
          body: |
            - Dependency updates

            Auto-generated by [create-pull-request][1]

            [1]: https://github.com/peter-evans/create-pull-request
          branch: test
          base: test-*
```